# setbuf in class c++

Tags: c++, printf, stm32, mbed

I got problem with setbuf in class which I ported from mbed to use in my STM32 project with LCD display to have method `printf`, this is my constructor:

```
Stream::Stream(void) : _file(NULL) {
    /* open ourselves */
    char buf[12]; /* :0x12345678 + null byte */
    std::sprintf(buf, ":%p", this);
    _file = std::fopen(buf, "w+");
    setbuf(_file, NULL);
}
```

Program is stoping when get to line:

```
setbuf(_file, NULL);
```

and I need a help.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you don't check the return from fopen, and it could be NULL.  Note that standard file functions aren't required do null checks themselves.  Perhaps you don't have permission to create that file in the current directory?

Comment: Change to a directory where you are allowed to create the file? Use a full path to /tmp? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the STM32's do not have filesystem calls implemented, so `fopen` and friends will not work. If you want to store / read data you'll need to look at the Non-Volatile Memory (NVM) or EEPROM APIs for your MCU. This is unfortunately not standardized between STM32 MCUs.